# Blocking specific ads in the Google Custom Search

Tags: google-adsense, google-programmable-search-engine

I don't seem to find way to block competitor sites in the Google Custom Search product though I'm able to in normal AdSense ad units.

I've tried to search in Google here and there but could not find answer to this.

Is there any alternative to Google Custom Search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to blocking competitor ads, [Google Site Search](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72325) does provide this feature:  [Google Site Search vs Google Custom Search](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72326)  Here's how: [Disable Ads](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=70354)

If you mean blocking competitor sites entirely from appearing in search results, you could try using the [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview):

> The Google Custom Search API lets you develop websites and programs to retrieve and display search results from Google Custom Search programmatically. With this API, you can use RESTful requests to get either web search or image search results in JSON or Atom format.

Comment: You've not answered exactly what I've asked. I understand that there is no way to block ads in CSE as for normal ad units. There is alternative : Google Site Search which allows blocking ads though.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your comment. I did suggest Google Site Search. It's unclear what you're asking about (i.e., "ads" in your title or "sites" in your question).

Comment: Just like as in normal ad units can we block specific ads from CSE product? This is what I'm asking.

Comment: Your question asks how to "block competitor `sites` in the Google Custom Search". Regardless, both my suggestions will allow you to block ads (the first one you repeated in your comment for some reason). It might be helpful to others if you make your questions a bit clearer. For example, "Is there any alternative to Google Custom Search?" isn't very specific.